# Control on led by health bar percentage in league of legends

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, ocr, tesseract

I made a code to control on a led by health percentage changing in league of legends. I used python and OCR to detect the health and send the health numbers to Arduino to control the led to make it blink with a  3 seconds delay when the health > 80% and blink for 1 second delay when the health < 80%.

The problem is that the led only blink with a 3 seconds delay for all health percentages. what shall I do ? thx in advance

Python code:

```
 import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import os
import pytesseract

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)
#This loop allows opencv to capture the screen continuously
while True:

  img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=[840, 1020, 940, 1050 ])

  
  img_np = np.array(img)

  frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  text = pytesseract.image_to_string(frame)
 
  v3=-1
  if "/" in text:
    x = text.split("/")
    try:
        v1 = int(x[0])
        v2 = int(x[1])
        v3 = int((v1/v2)*100) 
        if v3<=100: 
           print(str(v3))
           v4= str(abs(v3))
           ser.write(b'v4')
           time.sleep(0.1)
           time.sleep(2)
           

          
    except:
        pass
   
  
  
  cv2.imshow("Screen", frame)

  if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Arduino code

```
const int led=8;
String value;
int i;

void setup() 
   { 
      Serial.begin(9600); 
      pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
      Serial.println("Connection established...");
   }
 
void loop() 
   {
     while (Serial.available())
        {
             value = Serial.read();
             i = value.toInt();
             if (100 >= i > 80)
             {
                digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    
                delay(3000);
                digitalWrite(led, LOW);
             }
             else if (0 <= i < 80)
             {
                digitalWrite(led, HIGH);    
                delay(500);
                digitalWrite(led, LOW);
             }
             else { digitalWrite(led, LOW);
             }
        }
     
   }
```

enter code here

Comment: this is not a debugging service. you should narrow down the problem yourself. for example you should print the value received by the Arduino to find out wether the problem is on the Arduino or the Python side of your project... you don't need us for that break your project down into parts and check every one of them. do you get the correct OCR result, do you send the correct value, do you receive the correct value. that's all things you can find out by simple prints. you don't need our expert knowledge for this

Comment: thanks for the advice, I really appreciate that. I made sure that the python side is okay. but how can I monitor the Arduino output? because when I try serial monitor it gives me an error that the port is busy because python uses that port

Comment: either attach a second serial interface to your arduino (ttl to usb adapter, or a logic analyzer) or even simpler have your Arduino send back each received byte back to python

Answer (score 0):

I assume in `ser.write(b'v4')` that you don't need " ' " since now all you're sending is the string "v4" regardless of it's value.

Comment: thanks for the advice. But python sends an error that it's an Unicode string

Comment: You still have to turn v4 to to a byte string, that's what the 'b' in `ser.write(b'v4')` was used for. but since you can't use it anymore, I think `ser.write( str.encode(v4) )` might suit your situation.

Answer (score 0):

`Serial.read()` reads only 1 byte of data. If more bytes come in during your `delay()`, still the oldest byte is read. That means that your Serial port might be completely filled with values larger than 80.
You should do the 2 following things:

1. break up your arduino program to make sure, that you actually receive and evaluate the correct values on the port in a reasonable time.
2. do the LED blinking without `delay()`. Here is one of many tutorials how to do it: https://www.forward.com.au/pfod/ArduinoProgramming/TimingDelaysInArduino.html

Comment: thank you for the advice, I really appreciate that. How can I monitor the Arduino output? because when I try serial monitor it gives me an error that the port is busy because python uses that port.

Comment: You have to do it with your python program, because it is using the serial port. 
Another possibility is to use a serial console to send the data that should be used by the arduino. If you want to use the Arduino IDE serial monitor, you have to be aware, that it is always sending ASCII characters, not binary numbers.